# Is it possible to separate two Windows Editions from an iso?

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have an iso image file whose content is Windows 10 x86 and Windows 10 x64 editions.

Is it possible to separate both Windows 10 x86 and Windows 10 x64 from that iso image successfully?

If possible, how can I do it?

Comment: You might want to look in to the [DISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/dism---deployment-image-servicing-and-management-technical-reference-for-windows) tool that comes with windows.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Understanding the problem helps us generate an answer the solves your problem despite not doing what you want to do to solve it.  Helpful for those problems, where a user wants to do something, that doesn't or won't actually solve their actual problem.

Comment: I believe, "Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) is a command-line tool". Please let me know, how to use it and what command I need for separating both (Windows 10 x86 and Windows 10 x64) from an iso image?

Comment: I have a single iso for both (Windows 10 x86 and Windows 10 x64). I want two individual iso for both. That's why I would like to separate.

Comment: @GNS I believe what Ramhound wanted to know is why do you want to separate it out to two individual isos?

Comment: If you use the USB creation tool, you can create/download a single edition. Basically download the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question.

But maybe you need the .iso-file as an install-media.

As example, in Win7 you could change or create the file ei.cfg to allow to show all avaiable Windows versions to install from the respective media.

Maybe it's the same for Win10.

> /sources/ei.cfg (change [VL]{0})
>
> /sources/PID.txt (Productkey for automated register)

Comment: The file size of Windows 10 iso that I have is about 5GB. That iso has both Windows 10 x86 and Windows 10 x64. And I believe because of both editions, its size is 5GB. And I would like to decompose this iso into two separate iso files (for Windows 10 x86 and for Windows 10 x64). That’s why I would like to decompose it.

Comment: Normal after an installation the system takes around 16-20GB. The installation-media can content different features fro different OS-versions, as the installation file seems compressed. You could use the same install media for multiple installations, with the respective Productkey.