# Get enterprise account login option on Windows 10 start up process

Tags: windows-10, office365, windows-installation, azure-activedirectory

I made a USB Windows 10 installer. With this installer, I clean installed a MS Surface Pro 4 and a couple VMs. Every time on the setup process, I got asked to choose to login via a Microsoft Account (outlook.com) or a Enterprise Account (Office365, Azure). I want to login via an enterprise account!

Now I have two HP Spectre laptops. I performed the clean install, but every time on setup, I just get the option to login via personal Microsoft Account (outlook.com). It seems, Windows 10 Home is *embedded* on the devices. I don't want to add the license on the installer, because the license gets issued via the enterprise account.

How do I always get the option to login via an enterprise account on Windows 10 set up process?

Comment: There is a file on the ISO which determines which editions of Windows it can install.  You must modify this text file when creating the installation media to indicate which edition you want to be installed.  This will allow you to install Windows 10 Professional on a system that came with Windows 10 Home. You, of course, have to provide your own license in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add my product key permanently to a Windows 10 install USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1373753/how-can-i-add-my-product-key-permanently-to-a-windows-10-install-usb-drive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1140964/is-it-possible-to-separate-two-windows-editions-from-an-iso/1140968#1140968

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa

Comment: You would have to upgrade to the proper edition after you log into the machine if you don't want to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Last time I did a clean install on a coworker's laptop, there still was this option, barely visible at the bottom left corner of the screen, to create a local account instead of linking your install to an existing account, be it domain, MS or anything else, but that was six months ago. Could have been removed from the setup process, now that MS wants to force users into ditching local accounts. EDIT: apparently, you still can, but you have to make sure you have no Internet access: https://www.howtogeek.com/442609/confirmed-windows-10-setup-now-prevents-local-account-creation/

Comment: Non of the suggestions worked. I added added PID.txt and ei.cfg, and the HP Spectre always starts with the Home license on setup, without the option to enroll it into the company

Comment: Finishing the setup as Home and then changing account to Enterprise seems like the solution. Did you try it? What were the problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the Windows 10 Home license is embedded into your computer,
the installation is probably picking it up from the BIOS, where the serial
is burnt. There is no way to prevent this from happening automatically.

The only solution is to finish the setup as Home version,
and only then changing account to Enterprise.

Reference:
[How to change the product key on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-product-key-windows-10).